# Terraform with containerized lambda function and API Gateway

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, terraform, dockerfile, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to build an infrastructure with Terraform where an API Gateway triggers a lambda function.
It was working fine until I decided to make this function containerized.

## Terraform file :

```
# Create ECR repository
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "repo" {
  name = "my-app"
}

# Build docker images and push to ECR
resource "docker_registry_image" "repo" {
  name = "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest"

  build {
    context    = "../visitors_count"
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}

# Create the lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  function_name = "visitor_count"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  image_uri     = "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest"
  package_type  = "Image"
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecr_policy" {
  name = "ecr_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "ECRPermissions",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : [
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage"
        ],
        "Resource" : "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

# Create the role for lambda
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

# Attach to the lambda role a basic CloudWatch policy
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "basic_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

# API GATEWAY
# Create a REST API
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api" {
  name = "rest_api"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "api_resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "visitors_count"
}

# Create the GET method for the API
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "api_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

# Create integration between lambda function and the API gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.api_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.invoke_arn
}

# Allow the API Gateway to talk to the lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.test_lambda.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.myregion}:${var.accountId}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_method.api_method.http_method}${aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.path}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha256(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.api_method.id,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.integration.id,
    ]))
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# Create named reference to the deployment
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api.id
  stage_name    = "Prod"
}
```

## Dockerfile :

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

COPY visitors_count.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "visitors_count.visitors_count" ]
```

## CloudWatch logs:

```
2023-04-15T19:22:15.180+02:00   START RequestId: fadfa33d-801b-407a-aced-db5fd05d4f56 Version: $LATEST

2023-04-15T19:22:15.320+02:00   2023-04-15T17:22:15.320Z fadfa33d-801b-407a-aced-db5fd05d4f56 Task timed out after 3.16 seconds

2023-04-15T19:22:15.320+02:00   END RequestId: fadfa33d-801b-407a-aced-db5fd05d4f56

2023-04-15T19:22:15.320+02:00   REPORT RequestId: fadfa33d-801b-407a-aced-db5fd05d4f56 Duration: 3162.69 ms Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 21 MB
```

The ECR repo is created without issues, the terraform apply goes through without issues, all seems good but the API endpoint doesnt work.

When I try to access it I should be seeing something like

`{"visitors": "7"}`

But it's loading for couple of seconds and I get :

`{"message": "Internal server error"}`

edit: I tested the container locally, with my credentials, and it works fine. So it might be a permissions issue, but as you can see on my terraform file, the lambda role is set correctly..

Comment: "Internal server error" means you need to go look at the Lambda function's logs to see what the actual error message is. Without seeing the actual error message, anyone here trying to help would only be guessing at what the issue is.

Comment: But I already posted the messages from the lambda logs. At the bottom of my post.This is all I get when the function is invoked

Comment: Oh I see. So it's timing out after 3 seconds. Have you tried increasing the timeout setting to allow it more time?

Comment: I increased it to 10 seconds. The issue stay exactly the same.